# How can I remove transformer windings from wooden template?

Tags: transformer

I usually wind my larger MOT transformers by using a 2x4 as a template, then I push the zip-tied winding off the 2x4 and into the E section of transformer. As I knew I would be fighting for the last turn on this specific winding, I REALLY wound it tight. I cannot get it off. I've tried slowly punching down each side with a hammer and wood buffer. I've lubed it up with some olive oil. I've got a big clamp holding the "buldge" (mine doesn't really have one since it's so tight). I REALLY do not want to have to rewind this one. I'm sure I can come up with a primitive violent way to get it off, but I would love to hear from someone with a clever idea or has been in this frustrating situation before. Thanks. Picture attached[image]

Comment: Saw the end off and drill out the 2x4.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it primitive or violent to cut the 2X4 off next to the coil. If you can't push it at all, you might need to drill a big hole and carefully cut the wood. You might need to buy or borrow some tools. It looks like you used PVC insulated wire. You should have used magnet wire.

Comment: Sigh, yea that way makes the most sense. Thanks. Yea enameled copper would clearly make more sense here, but I haven't found a place to get it locally or an online provider that will accept strange trades.l

Comment: What if I put like 150-250 amps through it for a second or two? Do you think that might expand it enough to make any significant difference?

Comment: If the 2x4 is moist, which it probably is, expose it to hot dry air and it may shrink enough to get the winding off. Otherwise, cut both sides and bore it out with a drill press. A hand saw will let you cut closer to the winding than any power tool I know of. Which is important, because you would ideally like the drill bit to go all the way through.

Comment: In the future, use a split form. Two wedges that slide together to make the form (could still be made from a 2x4 with a diagonal cut). Good luck! If you get it off, come back and answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cut both sides off, one only close to the edge, maybe drill some big holes, and split it with a BF hammer and a chisel.

You could also try whaling on the longer end with a dead blow hammer to try and shatter it after drilling the holes.

Personally, I have a small benchtop 12 ton hydraulic press that would be more controlled or a 3 ton arbor press (that might not be strong enough). A big C-clamp or large bench vise might work just as well, but leave enough room on at least one end to get ahold of the 2x4 or you may actually make things worse!

I think oil or soapy water would just make the wood swell.

Your PVC jacket is probably good for about 90°C (but do check the rating on the markings) so you could try leaving it in an oven for 24 hours (or enclose it in an air tight box with fresh dessicant from the hobby store) to dry and shrink the wood. Drilling it first would make that process faster. An hour or two in a vacuum chamber might also do the trick (again, drilling the center out would expose more wood).

Answer (score 1):

I'm accepting Spehro's answer but still wanted to share what I did. I cut one of the sides off so the wood was flush with wire. Then, I just used a sturdy knife and a hammer as sort of a chisel to knock edge pieces out until it caved in enough to where the wire freely slid off. Thanks for all the help. And yes, I know I won't be getting my deposit back (jk next tenant is getting new carpet anyways). Oh and the real challenge ended up being getting it on the E piece, as I was using Two E's so it had to share.[image]